# How to calculate the probability of a random variable given two independent variables?

Tags: probability

For example, to calculate $\mathbb{P}(C \mid X_1,X_2)$, I know $\mathbb{P}(C \mid X_1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(C \mid X_2)$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables. If there is a way to calculate the $\mathbb{P}(C \mid X_1,X_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to compute $P(C|X_1,X_2)$ knowing only $P(C|X_1)$ and $P(C|X_2)$.

Suppose that $C$ is the condition that a random integer in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ is divisible by $6$, and $X_1$ is the condition that the given integer is divisible by $2$, and $X_2$ is the condition that the given integer is divisible by $3$. $P(C|X_1)=\frac13$, and $P(C|X_2)=\frac12$, and $P(C|X_1,X_2)=1$.

Suppose instead that $C$ is the condition that the random integer is $3$ or $4$. Then $P(C|X_1)=\frac13$, and $P(C|X_2)=\frac12$, yet $P(C|X_1,X_2)=0$.